# speeding up griddata 4D interpolation with unstructured data

Tags: python, interpolation, 4d

I know there are some similar threads on this topic, but I read almost all of them, yet the solutions are not applicable to my specific (4D, unstructured data) case.
I want to interpolate my values (on points) on a 4D meshgrid. I use griddata of scipy, which works perfectly well, but is (as you might imagine) extremely slow.
It may not appear so when you test it, but I have to do it 5-10 times with different and sometimes larger data and griddata takes around 10 seconds sometimes.

Does anybody know of an interpolation method/functionality which can help me do it in a pythonic way without using griddata?
Unfortunately I can not consider the MATLAB griddata, although I know it's much more faster.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

points=np.random.rand(4,100000)
values=np.random.rand(100000)

#coordinates:
grid_1=np.random.rand(109)
grid_2=np.random.rand(69)
grid_3=np.random.rand(12)
grid_4=np.random.rand(5)

meshgrid_1,meshgrid_2,meshgrid_3,meshgrid_4=np.meshgrid(grid_1,grid_2,grid_3,grid_4,sparse=True)
grid4d=griddata(points.T,values,(meshgrid_1,meshgrid_2,meshgrid_3,meshgrid_4),method="nearest")
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You may have already read this - any reason you can't adapt this? https://gist.github.com/wgurecky/c117144a9a496754020aa2ce31159da0

Comment: It does not fit my 4 dimensional grid :/ can be used for 2d grid